# Exporting Contacts to a .csv file

Tags: wordpress, contacts, export, csv

How do I export all contacts to a .csv file?

Answer (score 7):

Do a search that finds all contacts (for example, Find Contacts and then search without entering anything), then select "All nnn contacts" and choose Export from the drop down menu. You can select all primary fields or specific fields to export.